# Customizing mezzanine to allow users to edit and publish their own blog

Tags: django, django-models, blogs, mezzanine

I am trying to create a multi user blogging platform using Mezzanine, where each user of the site will get a blogging dashboard for posting and editing their blogs. Is there a way in mezzanine to give some admin permissions to users like to add and manage their blogs? I dont want to allow users to access the Site Admin completely.

I explored other blogging packages but since i have already customized mezzanine for other use cases so difficult to move away. Basically trying to find a solution in mezzanine itself.

Could you please guide me how to achieve this in mezzanine.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly possible. You can create admin users that only have access to the blog app, and only their own blog posts will be listed.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Basically i should create the can_publish permission for a BlogPost model in mezzanine.blog app and then assign it to a User via its user_permissions attribute. Am i going in right direction or you meant something else?

Comment: I was just referring to the standard Django permissions created for each model.